# Phonegap EmailComposer with attachment is not attaching images from gallery

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using EmailComposer plugin to send an form to an custom email. At some point in the form, the user will be able to take pictures and/or upload images from the gallery to be send via email.

With the camera images, everything works fine. The problem is when it is taken from the phone gallery.

Here's the code I use to upload like that:

```
function upGal() {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(updatePhoto,
    function() {
      console.log('error')
    }, {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: 1,
      sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    }
  );
}
```

The `updatePhoto` function does this:

```
function updatePhoto(imageURI) {

  //right here I include the image on this array, to be fowarded as attachment later
  if (imageURI != 'nothing')
    photoArray.push(imageURI);

  //bellow here I just include an <img> tag with the imageURI as src

}
```

The image is included as an  tag successfully, but when I try to send the email, only the images taken by the camera are attached.

Is there any trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check that imageURI actually contains the complete path to the image and if necessary use something like this:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting "Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'resolveLocalFileSystemURI'", even though I'm calling it after deviceReady :s

Comment: Have you installed the 'file' plugin? cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file

Comment: Yes, it's listed at the local plugin list as well.

Comment: Got it...started a new app and reinstalled plugins all over again. However, I noticed the getFile method is returning something like "content://media/external/images/media/38" if it's a gallery image, without extension. What surprises me the most is that if I try to attach this, it won't work, but if I put it in an img tag, it does...